# How send massive emails to different recipients and with different content message

Tags: c#, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

Edit the question with more details, I am trying to send the following sendgridMessage, the content that changes is inside the personalizations property, as well as what specific email it will be sent to, with the content that is expected to be sent for each email.

The problem is that when I send it in a single request, I only receive the 1st and 3rd item of the customization, I don't receive the 2nd item

```
SendgridMessage
{
    From: 
    {
        Name: AccountSenderName,
        Email: EmailSender@mail.com
    },
    TemplateId: d-u7eu36eg6328te3example,
    Personalizations: 
    [
        {
            "Tos": 
            [
                {
                    Email: "johndoe@mail.com",
                    Name: "John"
                }
            ],
            "TemplateData": 
            {
                "UserName":"John Doe",
                "VehicleDescription":"Chevrolet Camaro 2010",
                "PolicyNumber": "XX-XXXX-0126",
                "EndPolicyDate":"15/05/2023"
            },
            "Ccs": NULL
        },
        {
            "Tos": 
            [
                {
                    Email: "johndoe@mail.com",
                    Name: "John"
                }
            ],
            "TemplateData": 
            {
                "UserName":"John Doe",
                "VehicleDescription":"Dodge Ram 2010 SLT",
                "PolicyNumber": "XX-XXXX-2030"
                "EndDate":"30/05/2023"
            },
            "Ccs": NULL
        },
        {
            "Tos": 
            [
                {
                    Email: "analee@mail.com",
                    Name: "Ana"
                }
            ],
            "TemplateData": 
            {
                "UserName":"Ana lee",
                "VehicleDescription":"BMW M3 2012",
                "PolicyNumber":"XX-XXXX-2159",
                "EndDate":"15/06/2023"
            },
            "Ccs": "johndoe@mail.com"
        }
    ]
}
SendGridClient sendGridClient = new(_configuration["SendGrid:ApiKey"]);

await sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(sendGridMessage);
```

Update:

Apparently the sendgrid service in the basic plan only allows sending one email per second, in this case, since I'm sending 3 in a row, it might get out of phase and only send 2.

Maybe it's the plan of the (basic) account, I'd like to test it with a business plan to see if that resolves it, so that's why the limit of sending emails that the account allows.

Meanwhile it occurs to me to make a loop, and make a delay of 1 second in my basic plan just to verify that all the emails are sent correctly, which in this case are 3

Comment: _I am trying to send, for example, 3 emails with different content for the same user_: Sounds like spam.

Comment: In this case, my application deals with car policies, and each user can have several cars with their respective policies, there is a time when if they do not pay their annuity automatically, they have to notify that their policy has been canceled, is a requirment It is not for spam reasons, sendgrid blocks that automatically

Comment: Take the example of airbnb, you host a house for a weekend, you receive the email with the details and you can also copy your friends or family, knowing that if you receive an email your friends or family will also be notified, I look for that when copying the mail with another person

Comment: I appreciate any help to resolve this issue, for now I was able to make it work, but it's not optimal, note that sendgrid allows you to process one email per second, I don't like a loop very much but it works, I'll keep looking if it can be done in just one request, in the same way I already requested support in Sendgrid

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I edited question details